# fragment run before fragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

There is `Fragment` which uses some values from main `FragmentActivity`. The `Fragment` is added statically (XML) and run before the main `FragmentActivity`.
Is there a way to fix a run order of `Fragments` (excluding dynamic style)?

There is a rule:
If the `Fragment` should always be in the **Activity**, use XML to statically add but if it's more complex use the Java-based approach.

My `Fragment` is always in Activity. However, `FragmentActivity` have to received common values/variables before fragment run.

Is dynamic style is only my way?

Comment: you should read fragment lifecycle.

Comment: and how it's fixed my problem? You offer me to create fragment onResume?

Comment: Fragment is attached to the Activity. So fragment does not run before activity. Read this  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. Then you can solve your problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple, this is `life cycle` log for fragment within activity,

```
05-20 10:54:22.014: I/ActivityAndFragmentLifeCycle.java(6211): onCreate() Before setContentView() 
05-20 10:54:22.054: V/TestingFragment.java(6211): onAttach()
05-20 10:54:22.054: V/TestingFragment.java(6211): onCreate()
05-20 10:54:22.054: V/TestingFragment.java(6211): onCreateView() 
05-20 10:54:22.054: I/ActivityAndFragmentLifeCycle.java(6211): onCreate() After setContentView() 
05-20 10:54:22.064: V/TestingFragment.java(6211): onActivityCreated()
05-20 10:54:22.064: V/TestingFragment.java(6211): onStart()
05-20 10:54:22.064: I/ActivityAndFragmentLifeCycle.java(6211): onStart()
05-20 10:54:22.064: I/ActivityAndFragmentLifeCycle.java(6211): onResume()
05-20 10:54:22.064: V/TestingFragment.java(6211): onResume()
05-20 10:54:22.074: V/TestingFragment.java(6211): onPause()
05-20 10:54:22.074: I/ActivityAndFragmentLifeCycle.java(6211): onPause()
```

Here, `Activity's onCreate()` first get called. The main work of `onCreate()` is to inflate view. For that `setContentView()` get calling. At that time `Fragment's onCreateView()` get called.

`ActivityAndFragmentLifeCycle.java` extends with `FragmentActivity` and `TestingFragment.java` ectends with `Fragment`

Finally, if your activity variables value want to be alive within your fragment means you need to initialize those before `setContentView()` of your `FragmentActivity` or you need to go with programmatic fragment attachment.

Comment: to define the variables before setContentView() gives predicted result. Thanks man for your help.